# Error in estimating pi by Taylor expansion

Tags: python, function, math, taylor-series

I am trying to calculate the value of pi, but there is some semantic error in my logic which I am not able to figure out.

```
def taylor(precision):
    iter = 1
    sum = 0
    fx = 100
    sign = 1

    while (abs(fx) > precision):

        if not iter % 2 == 0:
            print(sign)
            sum += ((1 / (iter)) * sign)

        my_pi = 4 * (sum)
        fx = math.pi - my_pi
        iter += 1
        sign *= -1

    return my_pi
```

This results in an infinite loop.

I am supposed to use this series and find `my_pi` to a particular precision:

**π/4 = (1/1) - (1/3) + (1/5) - (1/7) + (1/9) -  ...**

Pretty new to programming, any help would be amazing!

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous it's resulting in an infinite loop.

Comment: And what does `precision` represent?

Comment: If you stepped through this line-by-line with a debugger, you'd likely find the issue very quickly. If you're still coding without knowing how to use a debugger, you're going to have a very hard time, since a debugger is an absolutely critical tool for software development. Pycharm has a debugger built-in - I'd recommend that for a beginner.

Comment: Thank you for the tip @RandomDavis, will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part here

```
if not iter % 2 == 0:
```

means you only sum when the iteration is not an even number, i.e., 1, 3, 5, ....
However, you alternate the sign every iteration, including that of the even iterations.

As a result, you get `1/1 + 1/3 + 1/5 + ...`.

Instead, try

```
        if not iter % 2 == 0:
            print(sign)
            sum += ((1 / (iter)) * sign)
            sign *= -1 # move the sign assignment here
```